# I am unable to sum my array because I think that it is being stored as multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

```
for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(1, m-1):
        a = np.sum(u[i][j])
        print("sum = ", a)
```

When I run this code it just prints out the values of u[i][j] and not the sum of these values.

```
u[i][j] = 10.0
10.006282725965008
10.018656940304817
10.036934387954467
10.060929709315529
10.09046035701636
10.12534651637516
10.16541102945263
10.21047932258388
10.260379337282082
10.314941464408948
10.373998481509876
10.437385493214036
10.504939874602194
10.576501217447468
10.65191127923653
10.731013934881009
10.813655131031123
10.899682842905593
10.988947033554055
11.081299615470174
11.176594414475591
11.274687135796801
11.375435332258856
11.478698374521604
11.584337423285957
11.692215403399317
11.802196979791036
11.914148535170309
12.02793814942053
12.143435580625656
12.260512247665599
12.379041214319123
12.498897174814157
12.619956440766764
12.742096929451419
12.865198153346483
12.9891412109001
13.113808778462937
13.239085103335473
13.364855997878626
13.491008834637794
13.617432542431397
13.744017603356207
13.87065605066278
13.99724146745538
14.123668986171829
14.249835288799703
14.375638607786316
14.500978727600879
14.625756986908184
14.749876281314098
14.87324106664404
14.995757362716542
15.117332757574852
15.237876412140386
15.357299065252723
15.475513039061617
15.592432244737337
15.707972188466462
15.822049977701013
15.934584327629603
16.04549556784001
16.1547056491434
16.262138150531044
16.367718286235256
16.471372912866805
16.57303053660195
16.67262132039279
16.77007709117535
16.86533134705057
16.958319264413905
17.04897770500997
17.13724522288933
17.223062071245103
17.30637020910775
17.387113307876973
17.465236757670322
17.540687673468693
17.613414901039484
17.68336902261878
17.75050236233456
17.81476899135342
17.87612473273397
17.934527165970557
17.989935631211583
18.042311233137184
18.091616844481656
18.137817109186503
18.180878445170528
18.220769046703957
18.25745888637408
18.290919716630427
18.32112507089799
18.3480502642476
18.371672393612954
18.39197033754437
18.408924755489863
18.422518086594533
18.432734548009854
```

Answer (score 4):

This code is correctly taking the `sum` of `u[i][j]`, the trivial sum of *one item*,  one cell in the two-dimensional array of numbers.

This code  sums  everything in the 2-d array.

```
a = np.sum(u)
print("sum = ", a)
```

This code  prints the sum of *each row*, in turn.

```
for i in range(len(u)):
        a = np.sum(u[i])
        print("sum = ", a)
```

Note that your `range` statements are probably wrong. `range(1,n)` gives, if for example, `n` is `4`, the values `1,2,3`. You want `range(n)` , which  would give `0,1,2,3`. More directly,`range(len(u))`.

Or even better

```
for row in u:
    a = np.sum(row)
    print ("sum=", a)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful!